# Feature rendering issue in Geoserver WMS layer at larger zoom scale

Tags: geoserver

I am using Geoserver 2.15.1 version to display PostGIS data as WMS layer at client side. There will be a rendering problem in my WMS layer, some dense areas are not visible in larger scale as marked in the below snapshot. Those area are getting generated when zooming closer to the particular location.

Is there any way in GeoServer to make the features visible at all scale levels? I have tried **MinScaleDenominator** and **MaxScaleDenominator**, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian Turton. Its resolved my problem